# Insert text into the element, then check if the element has that text

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In a Rails app I insert text into the elements via ajax. But then, I need to check, if a similar element has any text. I do it in such way:

```
$('.game-card-name').empty();
$('.game-card-description').empty();
$('.game-card-review').remove();
$('.game-card-name-back').empty();

<% @games.order(created_at: :asc).each_with_index do |game, index| %>
  $('#game-card-<%= index %> .front .game-card-image').css('background', 'asset_url(<%= game.game_image.url(:small) %>), no-repeat;');
  $('#game-card-<%= index %> .front .game-card-name').text('<%= game.title %>');
  $('#game-card-<%= index %> .front .game-card-description').text('<%= game.description.truncate(110) %>');
  $('#game-card-<%= index %> .front').append('<%= link_to 'Review', game, class: 'game-card-review' %>');
  $('#game-card-<%= index %> .back .game-card-statistics .game-card-name-back').text('<%= game.title %>');


  if($('#game-card-<%= index %> .front .game-card-name').text().trim().length == 0) {
    $('#game-card-<%= index %>').hide();
  } else {
    $('#game-card-<%= index %>').show();
  }

<% end %>
```

My `if` condition doesn't work. I think the reason is that ajax do it asynchronously. Is there a way to execute the code in an appropriate order? Thanks.

Comment: I dont know the exact task you're trying to accomplish, but wouldn't it be easier to just server-render a partial and replace the HTML on the page via AJAX altogether instead of having some server-generated jQuery that just throws the content away and replaces it with something else?

Comment: Yes, thanks for an idea. But for some reason, partial isn't working. I may be missing smth., so I did it with appending HTML via js. Maybe later I'll get to it, and make it a partial.

Comment: The usual thing is `$('#some-id').html("<%= j render partial: 'some-partial', locals: { some: 'variables' } %>")`, as far as I know